# Install Python 2.6 on Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, python

I want to install Python 2.6, but as it's still experimental for Debian Linux, I'm wondering what my best course of action is.  Is the right idea to install it into `/usr/local` for my system and then update the python sym link in `/usr/bin` to point to that version?  Are there other considerations or ways to do it I should be thinking about?

Comment: I just compiled it myself and installed in `/usr/local`. Both 2.6 and 3.1.

Comment: Don't touch `/usr/bin` at all, you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `altinstall` make target instead of the `install` target will create a `python2.6` executable, without touching the existing `python` link or executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the python on a different location and when using the binary in any other programs, use the full path to the binary where you have installed.